# jquery validate reCaptcha

Tags: php, jquery, recaptcha, jquery-validate

I am having some problems to validate this form with the jquery Validate plugin, I just dont get any response when the response is valid, and I dont have any idea why... 
Here is the html:

```
 <form id="signin_form"  action="" method="post">

<div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display:none">

       <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>
       <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color:red">Incorrect please try again</div>

       <p><span class="recaptcha_only_if_image">Enter the <br />words above:</span>
       <span class="recaptcha_only_if_audio">Enter the numbers you hear:</span>

       <span><input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" /></span></p>

       <div class="get_another_captcha"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">Get another CAPTCHA</a></div>
       <div class="recaptcha_only_if_image"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('audio')">Get an audio CAPTCHA</a></div>
       <div class="recaptcha_only_if_audio"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.switch_type('image')">Get an image CAPTCHA</a></div>

       <div class="help"><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.showhelp()">Help</a></div>

     </div>

     <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=public_key">
     </script>
     <noscript>
       <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=public_key"
            height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
       <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
       </textarea>
       <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
            value="manual_challenge">
     </noscript>

        <p><span></span><span> <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn-submit" />     </span></p>

</form>
```

This is the javascript:

```
$("#signin_form").validate({
    rules: {
        recaptcha_response_field: {
            required: true,
            remote: { 
                url:"verify.php",
                type:"post",
                async:false,
                data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" +    $('#recaptcha_challenge_field').val() + "&recaptcha_response_field=" + $('#recaptcha_response_field').val()
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        recaptcha_response_field: {
            required: "*",
            remote: "Invalid captcha"
        }
    }
});
```

and the verify.php is the following:

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "private_key";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
if (!$resp->is_valid) {  

 echo "false";
 }
 else{ 
 echo "true";
 }
```

Does anyone have any idea why?, I just cant seem to find the problem I have been trying so hard.., no idea why when the captcha is right doesn't happen anything... 
Thanks soo much in advance

Comment: Hey! try testing your file accessing it through browser but setting the values manually in the "recaptcha_check_answer" function.

Comment: owww... Oscar... that is you ... cool.. I am going to try to do that...

Comment: oww lol.. set the values manually first and then do a print_r($resp) and take a look what this outputs, this way you will know if the method is working good or not :-) then I have other things for you to do

Comment: I am sorry I am too stupid for this world, my son is called Oscar too :)

Comment: cool! :) hey, do you have skype or something so I can help you online, it will be better

Comment: Hi Oscar I got ReCaptchaResponse Object ( [is_valid] => 1 [error] => )

Comment: Yeah one second i need to search for my password...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17345/discussion-between-oscar-jara-and-mariaz)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code is that it's getting the `recaptcha_response_field` value when setting the rules, not when they are verified.

Fixed code:

```
$("#signin_form").validate({
    rules: {
        recaptcha_response_field: {
            required: true,
            remote: { 
                url:"verify.php",
                type:"post",
                async:false,
                data: {
                    recaptcha_challenge_field: function(){ return $('#recaptcha_challenge_field').val(); },
                    recaptcha_response_field: function(){ return $('#recaptcha_response_field').val(); }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        recaptcha_response_field: {
            required: "*",
            remote: "Invalid captcha"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This fixes it - it forces jQuery.validate to get the values in the challenge/response fields when the form is submitted. The original code tries to get those values on page load (and there's no value in the response field at that time, of course)

Comment: I think this way is good, but has the disadvantage. The browser sends a request to the server each time a user prints a character. So check long runs. I suggest adding **onkeyup: false**.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo json_encode(true);
```

instead of

```
echo 'true';
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are not using the response coming from `verify.php`.

This is the tutorial for getting the response and using them.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: the response should be true or false, how can i use that in this code, i was thinking when it is true... it automatically it passes the condition....